# What's this hole in the Cabbage leaf?

Tags: pest-control, plant-health, leaves, pests, cabbage

What's this hole I just discovered in the leaf of this otherwise very healthy Cabbage?  I've got yellow insect cards nearby, and beneficial nematodes in the soil, which have collectively done wonders for little flies.  Is this a chance visit from an insect?  A sun or chemical burn?

[image: hole I just discovered in the leaf of this otherwise very healthy Cabbage]
[image: hole I just discovered in the leaf of this otherwise very healthy Cabbage]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a snail or a slug to me... caterpillars are also a common cabbage pest, but they usually start at the edges.

Answer (score 1):

This is a healthy, productive plant.  A few holes, tears or lost leaves won't ruin a plant's vigor. The inside holes are probably slugs, snails or flea beetles. The edges are probably being munched on by rodents, slugs. Plants are built to be rugged, hardy.  If the damage begins to increase, you'll have figured out what to expect and you'll be on top of things.  The cool thing is you are observant.

Brassicas are beloved nurseries for flea beetles and root maggots, you should check around the base of the stalk down into the soil for signs of larvae, maggots. These look newly transplanted? Plenty of time to get row cloth, I hope, to keep insects away from plants. Actually, I just went out and got some row cloth to do the same thing. I remembered an old vegetable garden where I'd had huge, gorgeous cabbages/cauliflowers that were great one day and dying the next. What I learned is there's a fly (moth?) that lays its eggs in the dirt around the base of a cabbage or the Brassicas. The larva feed on the roots and it will take weeks to even notice there might be a problem.

I try not to run out of row cloth, great stuff.

Comment: Absolutely. I wrote that poorly!! That's not at all what I meant...after I reread my answer...it took awhile for me to understand as well! Sorry and thanks jmusser!